# Weird exception when trying to automate MS Word from vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-word

I use the following vb.net function to purely save Word documents (no text input whatsoever, I'm only interested in mass creation of empty word documents at the moment):

```
Sub createDoc(ByVal cname As String, ByVal acctype As String)
    counter += 1
    wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Add
    wordDoc.SaveAs(OFDD.SelectedPath & "\" & cname & "_" & acctype & ".docx")
    wordDoc.Close()
End Sub
```

The OFDD variable is the name of a folder browser vb component, and its SelectedPath property combined with the cname and acctype parameters provide me with the name of the Word document I want to create and save. Here are the declarations of the counter, wordDoc and wordApp variables:

```
 Private Shared counter As Integer = 0
 Private wordApp As New Word.Application
 Private wordDoc As Word.Document
```

The wordDoc variable is assigned to a Document object by use of the second line of code in the subroutine createDoc. However, it appears that at the 83rd time that I'm trying to retrieve a document object and assign it to wordDoc I receive an exception stating that "Command failed" . I can tell that it's the 83rd time I enter the function because in my catchblock I print the value of counter in a message box, right after printing details about the received exception and right before I release my used resources and end the process.

Worried about whether my system has limitations related to MS Word automation, I created another Visual Studio project (a Console project, this time), referenced the Microsoft.Interop.Office.Word namespace and wrote the following simple module:

```
Imports Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word
Module Module1

Sub Main()
    Dim wordApp As New Word.Application
    Try
        For i As Integer = 0 To 150
            Dim document As Word.Document = wordApp.Documents.Add()
            document.SaveAs("C:\WordTester\" & i & ".docx")
            document.Close()
        Next
    Catch
        wordApp.Quit()
    End Try
    Console.WriteLine("Document objects left in memory: " & _ 
                       wordApp.Documents.Count) ' zero
    Console.Read()
    wordApp.Quit()
End Sub

End Module
```

Which works perfectly. Checking my filesystem, I see 150 word files created in "C:\WordTester". Given all these efforts of mine, I'm really baffled as to why the first code I've written gets stuck at the 83rd effort to create and save a document, and any help would be immensely appreciated.

Thank you for your time,

Jason

Edit: Here is the edited version of createDoc which I reference in a comment below:

```
Sub createDoc(ByVal cname As String, ByVal acctype As String)
    counter += 1
    wordApp = New Word.Application
    wordDoc = New Word.Document
    wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Add
    wordDoc.SaveAs(OFDD.SelectedPath & "\" & cname & "_" & acctype & ".docx")
    wordDoc.Close()
    wordApp.Quit()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this.  Obviously I've had to insert a bit of assumed code, but this is pretty much what you should be doing:

```
Imports Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word

Public Class Class1

Private pWordApp As Word.Application
Private pintCounter As Integer = 0

Public Sub CreateWordDocuments()

    '--instanciate word:
    pWordApp = New Word.Application

    Dim dt As DataTable = GetYourDataEtc    'replace with however you get the data you loop around
    Dim OFDD As Object = GetYourFolderPathEtc   'replace Object and folder path call and 

    Try

        For Each dr In dt.Rows
            Dim cName As String = dr("cname")  'for example
            Dim acctype As String = dr("acctype") #for example

            CreateDoc(OFDD, cName, acctype)
        Next

    Catch ex As Exception
        '--some error code
    Finally
        pWordApp.Quit()
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(pWordApp)
    End Try

End Sub

Private Sub CreateDoc(ByVal OFDD As Object, ByVal cname As String, ByVal accType As String)

    Dim document As Word.Document = pWordApp.Documents.Add()
    document.SaveAs(OFDD.SelectedPath & "\" & cname & "_" & accType & ".docx")
    document.Close()

End Sub


End Class
```

Comment: Yes, it is always at the 83rd time. My input is taken from an SQL Server database query with about 250 records so I checked whether the input around row 83 might have NULL fields; this is not the case. My existing catch block has the following Message Box outputs:

 `MsgBox("Error : " & Err.Description & " from method: " & Err.Source & " in line " & Err.Erl & ".", vbCritical) 

MsgBox("Document Objects in memory: " & wordApp.Documents.Count) 

MsgBox("Counter variable value : " & counter) `

which I think would be verbal enough, perhaps?

Comment: I was meaning put another try catch block into the actual CreateDoc Routine and break on the error. Then interogate the word object to see whats up.

Comment: Booji Boy is right in what hes saying.  Your edited CreateDoc routine isn't a good idea though, as you are starting and closing word for each document.  Why not simply copy the working console code into a class.  Create the reference to word at the top, process each document the shut down word and dispose?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a garbage collection problem - the CLR is holding to many references to the word object and is word running out of some resource before garbage collection kicks in. The second function works because everything is scoped locally. You can change the code to scope things locally; also, calling dispose on the worddoc object will help.

Looks like there's no dispose. The proper way is to call the ReleaseComObject method

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa159887(office.11).aspx

Comment: Hmmm, I'm afraid I'm not quite clear on what you mean by "scoped locally". What should I change the nature of my code to in order to make sure that garbage collection doesn't screw things up?

Comment: Also, as far as calling "Dispose()" on the worddoc object is concerned, I'm receiving an exception stating that 'Public member  Dispose() on type "DocumentClass" not found'.

Comment: both the wordapp and word doc are declared in the sub (local scope) therefor both end up on the heap instead of the stack. The stack will be emptied after the sub finishes running. The first code has the wordapp and worddoc declared in the module and therefore (global scope) and will end up on the heap and will take longer to get cleaned up by the garbage collector

Comment: Wouldn't this be what I want, however? I mean, I want the objects to get cleaned up as late as possible, lest my wordDoc and wordApp objects start behaving incorrectly, the same way they do now.

It should also be noted that the hierarchy of the first code is as follows: class-> sub main -> central for loop which calls sub createDoc() if some requirements are met.

Comment: Yes, it will be slower to declare everything locally, but it will help with garbage clean up. something as simple changing the wordapp declaration to Dim wordApp As Word.Application and instantiate the wordApp = New Word.Application in the constructor may help. also set worddoc = nothing after calling close

Comment: I changed createDoc to what's being shown in an edit of my original post, yet I'm still experiencing the same error. It should also be noted that before I did this, I tried `System.GC.KeepAlive(wordApp)` and `System.GC.KeepAlive(wordDoc)` after all calls to this routine were made. The problem persisted.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a new instance of Word each time you create a document, I'd rather create ONE instance before the loop for single document creation and using this application object during the loop - this is the approach dunc has proposed.

NOTE: After the loop you release the COM object with Marshal.ReleaseCOMObject. I'd call this function also in the CreateDoc subroutine for the doc object. 
Please have a look at [this discussion about releasing COM objects](http://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2008/10/30/releasing-office-objects-net/) in Office automation.

Answer (score 0):

After looking into it for the better part of a day at work, I finally found out that  the problem didn't lie within the garbage collection process at all. Nor was I creating too many document objects. It just turns out that my database input contained records with double quotes and MS Word does not allow for double quotes in file names.

Thank you for your time and interest.